dispatchEvent isn't submitting form in nextjs
I'm trying to submit a form with
const submit = useRef(null)
submit.current.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', { bubbles: true })); // Trigger the submit event

It isn't submitting it properly. How can I resolve this? Here is my html form in nextjs.
<form className={styles['resume-form']} onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={submit}>
          <div className="relative">
            <input
              type="file"
              accept=".pdf, .doc, .docx"
              id="fileInput"
              className="hidden"
              onChange={handleFileChange}
            />
            <label
              htmlFor="fileInput"
              className="bg-yellow-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded cursor-pointer hover:bg-yellow-600"
            >
              Choose a file
            </label>
          </div>        
        <button type="submit" id="reviewer" className={styles['submit-button']}>Submit</button>
      </form>

